# Interferometry maximum wavelength for a set of baseline lengths

Tags: frequency, antennas, interferometry, radio-frequency

I am trying to understand phase ambiguity resolution for interferometry. Unfortunately, all I have are old power points and not really any notes or textbooks on the subject.

I have found in a power point for 3 antenna the equation:

$d_2 - d_1 \leq \dfrac{\lambda}{2}$

to find the minimum wavelength to not have phase ambiguities. I would like to extend this to 4 antenna, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Does 3 antenna mean 1 Tx and 2 separate Rx?

Comment: I believe it's 3 Rx. They're just receiving and measuring phase of an incident wave

Comment: Oh. I spent 20y in imaging radar at NASA, so always think Tx/Rx. So why only 2 distances, and why the factor of $\frac 1 2$ on the RHS (since radar is 2 way). Note also that unlike range or azimuth ambiguities, phase ambiguities are fix able, by the NP-hard problem of phase-unwrapping, which may get easier or harder for more than 2 signals. I need more time to think about it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to display the relevant Power Point page(s)?

Comment: I don't have access to them over the weekend, but I recognized a lot of the equations from phase calculation, however this link https://www.emsopedia.org/entries/passive-direction-finding-df-techniques-phase-comparison/ posts a lot of the same equations.